# Stage not started after hiding

Tags: java, javafx

I want show-hide form every 5 seconds. When form is hided - its not showing again. I dont understand why so.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
primaryStage.show();
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

Platform.runLater(() -> System.out.println("Inside Platform.runLater()"));


ScheduledExecutorService hider = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
hider.schedule(
 new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
   Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
     if (primaryStage.isShowing()) {
      primaryStage.hide();
     } else {
      primaryStage.show();
     }

    }
   });
  }
 }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

[ScheduledExecutorService.schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

> Creates and executes a one-shot action

For running an action periodically, use [ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

> Creates and executes a periodic action

Also after hiding the primary stage the runnable is not invoked again, so use  `setIconified(true)` instead of hiding:

```
      ScheduledExecutorService hider = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
                                                 hider.scheduleAtFixedRate(
           () -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
               if (!primaryStage.isIconified()) {
                   primaryStage.setIconified(true);
               } else {
                   primaryStage.setIconified(false);
               }
          }),
          5, //initial delay
          5, //period delay
          TimeUnit.SECONDS
     );
```

Consider an alternative implementation using javafx animation tools like `PauseTransition`:

```
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
    pause.setOnFinished(event ->{

         if (! primaryStage.isIconified()) {
             primaryStage.setIconified(true);
         } else {
             primaryStage.setIconified(false);
         }

         pause.play();
    });
    pause.play();
```